# Adjusting Spatial Accuracy of Ortho Imagery in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digital-image-processing, arcgis-10.5, accuracy, orthorectification

I have about 35 square miles of orthorectified, high resolution, aerial imagery that is broken down into 620 individual tiff files.  I have created a mosaic dataset of the imagery and I am working with ArcGIS 10.5 with all extensions.

I need to increase the accuracy of the imagery placement as the imagery was collected without the use of ground control and there are (x,y) errors of 1 to 3 feet across the area. I do have hundreds of ground control points that are survey quality and are visible throughout the imagery.  I also have a high accuracy DEM for the area created from LiDAR data, however, I really do not need to fully orthorectify the imagery again but rather just slightly spatially adjust the data.

Is there an ArcGIS tool available to correct this imagery?

I did look into using [Bundle Block Adjustment](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/ortho-mapping-overview.htm) but I am not sure if this is the best approach for the needed correction.

Comment: If georeferencing accept mosaic dataset as input, I'd work with whole set. Individual adjustment different to simple shift will distort edges.

Comment: You could use the Georeference toolbar http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Fundamentals_of_georeferencing_a_raster_dataset/009t000000mn000000/GUID-E0959E92-489D-4956-BF2B-B50170242E22/ but you may need to export the mosaic dataset to a single raster first. Perhaps an affine will be what you need (rotate & scale) but other methods are available (2nd, 3rd order and adjust) to transform the raster **but** @FelixIP is 100% correct that any other transform will render anything *outside your control points* subject to an uncertain transformation and no longer trustworthy.